# Multiple Azure queues

Tags: azure, queue, azure-queues

I am trying to workout the best implementation/approach to the following problem

I have customers using our win forms application which has a plugin which will connect to the Azure Queue to check if there are awaiting invoices for the connecting customer at pre conf intervals. If there is then the plugin will download the invoices into the customers local db. There are lots of customers using this application so all of them will connect to the queue. They will all need to download their own invoices

How I thought of implementing this was by having named queues for each customer (the customer GUID will identify the queue). So all the customers will use the same Account key/name to connect to the queue. Now the problem with this is that each customer has the account key/name in the dll which they can reflect and retrieve (smart customers). So is there a way I can encrypt the key/name or is there a better solution that somebody can suggest

Answer (score 3):

I think the only secure option is to stand up a web service somewhere that acts as a front-end to the queues.  Otherwise, as you said, you're leaking the account key to the client, which would allow any customer to read/change/delete any data in the account.